# How to put Maven Tycho Dependency in my Eclipse Plug-in?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho-surefire-plugin

I've created a new project using tycho 0.26.0, it runs with Eclipse 4 Neon.2, so all modules are building successfully using maven, now I am trying to add a new dependency in my project, I have created a jar and I want to use it in my project, but I don't understand so good how is it working.

I add I am using a target definition, so I have to add my configuration to this file, this will be used by my modules.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got your question right.
I assume you want to build an Eclipse RCP application with tycho and use an JAR file from one of your plug-ins.

The simplest solution is then to create a new plug-in project from this jar by using the **Plug-in from existing JAR Archives-Wizard**.

If you have done this, you can add a dependency from this new plug-in to your existing plug-ins. Don't forget to export all packages of the library, by opening Manifest.mf and adding all packages in the Runtime tab.

To get this running with maven you have also to add a pom.xml file to the new Plug-in. This link help me a lot with maven tycho (http://codeandme.blogspot.de/p/tycho-articles.html).

Btw. if you don't need this library as plain JAR, you can also create directly a Plug-in project instead of first creating a JAR and then creating a Plug-in project.

[image: Create a plug-in project from a jar]

Comment: Thank you, I've configured my project with maven and tycho, but my dependencies were not taken by the eclipse, so I've configured a directory dependencies to get all my maven dependencies and configured the eclipse to get all dependencies from this directory. Now I have another problem, I cannot start my application as standalone executable, so I need this to test the update site.